# Is it possible to address a web element using its webdriver object ID (temporary name)?

Tags: python, selenium

Language: python 2.7.8, explorer: IE 11, OS: Windows 7

I found the parent of a given web element by using:

```
elementParent = element.parent
```

Then:

```
print elementParent
```

I got:

```
selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x0000000003E92550
```

What does this string "0x0000000003E92550" represent? I gave it a name "webdriver object ID". Is it possible to address an element using this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this string ... represent?

What you see there, is the memory address of the variable that was returned (`element.parent`)

> Is it possible to address an element using this string?

You can refer to the address, but not in the way you want to.  Since you already have a new variable, `elementParent`, just refer to that.

```
txt = elementParent.get_text()
# for example
```